# Clang error following 'make' when building project from github

Tags: macos, gcc, cmake, clang

I'm building a project from github (https://github.com/marsicoLab/PROmiRNA) and have the following requirements on my mac (Big Sur 11.4); gcc 9.4, cmake 3.21.1, R 4.1.0.

After using cmake, which runs without error, I use make however this gives me the below errors:

```
clang: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
clang: error: clang frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.9)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
clang: note: diagnostic msg: Error generating preprocessed source(s).
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/PROmiRNA.dir/PROmiRNA.cpp.o] Error 254
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/PROmiRNA.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

A lot of other questions online with the same issue refer to XCode but I don't have it installed and am not a developer myself so don't think I need it..?

If anyone has any suggestions I'd really appreciate it, thanks :)

Comment: The project is C++ and that clang: error is during the C++ complication. Looking at the project a good way forward for you would be to build this on Linux using docker or a VM  with R installed. See the projects README under heading 'Prerequisites'.

Comment: Try using newer clang. The error message looks like an internal compiler bug.

Comment: You're not actually using gcc 9.4, as you say. It is clear you're using Apple Clang from the output.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, ended up working on linux :)